# QPainter drawLines method

Tags: c++, qt

I use the following code to draw the axes of a graph in qt:

```
...

static const std::array<const QPointF,10*2> horizontalAxis = {
    QPointF(0.f,0.f), QPointF(1.f,0.f),
    // Horizontal scales
    QPointF(0.f,0.f), QPointF(0.f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.125f,0.f), QPointF(0.125f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.25f,0.f), QPointF(0.25f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.375f,0.f), QPointF(0.375f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.5f,0.f), QPointF(0.5f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.625f,0.f), QPointF(0.625f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.75f,0.f), QPointF(0.75f,1.f),
    QPointF(0.875f,0.f), QPointF(0.875f,1.f),
    QPointF(1.f,0.f), QPointF(1.f,1.f)
};

static const std::array<const QPointF,6*2> verticalAxis = {
    QPointF(0.f,0.f), QPointF(0.f,1.f),
    // Vertical scales
    QPointF(0.f,0.f), QPointF(-1.f,0.f),
    QPointF(0.f,0.25f), QPointF(-1.f,0.25f),
    QPointF(0.f,0.5f), QPointF(-1.f,0.5f),
    QPointF(0.f,0.75f), QPointF(-1.f,0.75f),
    QPointF(0.f,1.f), QPointF(-1.f,1.f)
};

...

void Plot::paint(QPainter& p)
{
    int const width = p.device()->width();
    int const height = p.device()->height();
    Q_ASSERT(width > xpaddingLeft + xpaddingRight);
    Q_ASSERT(height > ypaddingTop + ypaddingBottom);

    if(dirty) {
        recalculate();
    }

    p.save();

    int const bottomLeftX = xpaddingLeft;
    int const bottomLeftY = height - ypaddingBottom;
    int const scaleX = width - xpaddingLeft - xpaddingRight;
    int const scaleY = height - ypaddingTop - ypaddingBottom;

    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing,false);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,false);

    QPen pen(QBrush(QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0)), 2);
    pen.setCosmetic(true);  // Do not apply scale to the pen
    p.setPen(pen);

    // Horizontal Axis
    p.resetTransform();
    p.translate(bottomLeftX,bottomLeftY);   // Origin at bottom left
    p.scale(scaleX,scaleSize); // y-axis points down. Only scale y to match the scale-mark size
    p.drawLines(&horizontalAxis[0], (int)horizontalAxis.size());

    // Vertical Axis
    p.resetTransform();
    p.translate(bottomLeftX,bottomLeftY);
    p.scale(scaleSize,-scaleY); // y-axis points up. Only scale x to match the scale-mark size
    p.drawLines(&verticalAxis[0], (int)verticalAxis.size());

    ...
}
```

This results in a graph like the following, with a weird artifact to the lhs (showing just the axes with no data loaded):
**Horizontal axis scales result in weird artifact to the LHS**
[image: Horizontal axis scales result in weird artifact to the LHS]

Commenting out all of the QPointF definitions for the horizontal scale definition removes this weird artifact. However commenting any individual pair of points doesn't seem to affect it. If I switch from using the drawLines() method, as follows, the stretching disappears.

```
    //p.drawLines(&horizontalAxis[0], (int)horizontalAxis.size());
    for(size_t k = 0; k < horizontalAxis.size()-1; k += 2) p.drawLine(horizontalAxis[k],horizontalAxis[k+1]);
```

And I get a result like the following without any artifacts (Showing just the axes with no data loaded):
**Horizontal axes scales show no switching**
[image: Horizontal axes scales show no switching]

Am I missing something or is this a bug in drawLines()?

I use the `drawLines()` function twice more to draw the vertical axis and actual data (as a line graph) without (apparent) issue but I want to be more certain that it won't result in odd artifacts in circumstances I haven't managed to test for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drawLines()` overload you are using is (from the Qt5 docs):

```
QPainter::drawLines (const QPointF* pointPairs, int lineCount)
```

May I draw your attention to the second parameter. It's called `lineCount`, not point-count, so you have to pass HALF the number of points:

```
assert (0 == horizontalAxis.size () % 2);
p.drawLines (&horizontalAxis[0], static_cast<int> (horizontalAxis.size () / 2));
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm embarrassed I missed that!

Comment: Was confusing the drawLines() and drawPolyline() method parameters. There's my excuse!